# Is it possible to see the restart history of an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, history, restart, application-restart

Is it possible to see the restart history of an Azure App Service?

I mean to see it in the GUI, not an API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can see it from `Activity log` in azure portal. Screenshot as below:

[image]