# Getting Azure App Service restarts as metric

Tags: c#, azure

Is it possible to get programmatically the number of app service restarts either as a metric or an alert. Specifically the programmatic equivalent of going to an Azure App service -> Diagnose and solve problems -> Web App restarted and get the dates and times of the restarts.

According to this: [Is it possible to see the restart history of an Azure App Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59678953/is-it-possible-to-see-the-restart-history-of-an-azure-app-service) the activity log also contains the data.

Ideally I want to access this from the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent interface i.e. in C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just use the code below to check the activity log, the `list` in the code is what you want.

Follow the steps below.

1.[Register an application with Azure AD and create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal).

2.[Get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret).

3.Navigate to the web app -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> add service principal of the AD App as an RBAC role e.g. `Contributor`, details follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

4.Then use the code below.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientId = "xxxxx";
            var clientSecret = "xxxxx";
            var tenantId = "xxxxx";
            var subscriptionId = "xxxxx";

            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                        .FromServicePrincipal(clientId,
                        clientSecret,
                        tenantId,
                        AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);


            var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
                        .Configure()
                        .Authenticate(credentials)
                        .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

            var logs = azure.ActivityLogs.DefineQuery()
                .StartingFrom(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
                .EndsBefore(DateTime.Now)
                .WithAllPropertiesInResponse()
                .FilterByResource("/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/joyweba")
                .Execute();

            List<IEventData> list = new List<IEventData>();

            foreach (var log in logs) {
                if ((log.OperationName.LocalizedValue == "Restart Web App") & (log.Status.LocalizedValue == "Succeeded")) {
                    list.Add(log);
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

[image]